# Is it possible to get the data that is sent to the printer driver using VB .NET?

Tags: vb.net, printing, driver

I wanted to ask if it is possible to get the data that is sent to the printer that is connect via USB cable. When the document is sent to the printer, the document data will be stored in a text file, but the print job will not be interrupted.